# proverb: A man's home is his castle

Tags: proverbs

I'd like to know whether the following scenario illustrates the proverb, "A man's home is his castle."

> Sir Henry Pellatt was a wealthy Canadian businessman. He ordered the construction of Casa Loma, which contains three buildings. They are the Casa Loma proper, which has a seven story-tower; the Hunting Lodge, which used to house the servants' quarters; and a huge stable. Together they take up over 6,000 square meters and are connected by a tunnel.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: How is this an English language question?

Comment: **free to do as he likes** is a sloppy paraphrase and I have no wish to get into a discussion of what may be the limits  upon freedom in one's home. What exactly is your question here? Are you asking for explanations of the proverb?

Comment: An Australian claimed that the quoted passage illustrates the proverb on the interpretation I offered.

Comment: RE: _An Australian claimed that the quoted passage illustrates the proverb on the interpretation I offered._ I never understand why people leave such pertinent details out of their questions. Had you delved into that a little bit more, there's a good chance this question wouldn't have three downvotes.

Answer (score 5):

The scenario doesn't illustrate the proverb, as the castle referenced doesn't actually stand for any physical castle.

[From dictionary.com,](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/a-man-s-home-is-his-castle) the definition is

> People enjoy the position of rulers in their own homes, and others have no right to enter without the householder's permission.

Think of a king defending his castle from threats.  Random, everyday people are not allowed into the private areas of said castle.  If you want to get into the private areas, you must either own the castle or have permission from the castle owner to go there.  In modern terms, this means that the man or other owner of the "castle" (which in this case is their house), needs to give you explicit permission in order for you to enter.

Comment: I agree. When I hear the proverb, I generally think of a very modest home, not a three-building complex with a seven-story tower.

Comment: Some people say the proverb also means the owner of the house is free to do what he likes. Does that apply to the scenario?

Comment: @Apollyon *Free to do what you like* applies to the proverb (rulers generally can do whatever they like), but the Casa Loma passage has nothing whatsoever to do with the proverb. In fact, only mentioning a literal castle without any other context misses the point of the proverb completely.

Comment: @JasonBassford  Sir Henry Pellatt had tunnel work done under his house. Does that count as an instance of freedom in one's home?

Comment: @Apollyon If the work were done under his house, it wouldn't have affected his freedom inside his house . . .  But you're missing the point entirely. A proverb is *figurative* not *literal*. And people have already answered your question: your passage is not an illustration of the proverb.

Comment: What would be a figurative illustration of the proverb, other than that the owner of a house can refuse entry?

Comment: @Apollyon - In most restaurants in the US, I can't smoke a cigarette. In some cities, it would generally be considered bad form to take a nap on a public bench in the subway station. The proverb _"A man's house is his castle"_ simply means I make the rules in my own house, so, for example, if I want to smoke a pipe at my dining room table, or take a nap on my sofa, or sing loudly while I walk around with in tattered clothes, I can. If someone else is using the proverb to talk about an ambitious building project, I suppose that could be done, but that's not how the proverb is generally applied.